# just installed sts 3.7.3 and tried to export java project

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I just installed sts 3.7.3 and tried to export java project and no export wizards are shown to select so I cannot export the project.

how to fix?

Comment: Export or import? Export project available on right click menu

Comment: FreezY, I clearly said "export" and I said there are "no export wizards to select from".